# ColorBox - Error: cboxElement missing settings object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, colorbox

What I'm trying to do is to play a video inside [ColorBox](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox) lightbox.

My HTML code is as follows. When I click on the link it should play the video.

```
<a href="http://cdn-azu-ns.viddy.com/media/video/0b2b103a-0c40-48a4-877a-64645ef5a0ae-high.mp4?t=634914421568400000" target="_blank" class="photo_link cboxElement iframe">Video</a>
```

What I do with Colorbox is as below. Load the video into lightbox.

```
jQuery(".iframe").colorbox({iframe:true, width:"80%", height:"80%"});
```

It gives me the below error.

```
Error: cboxElement missing settings object
```

ScreenShot

[image]

What should I do to fix this ? Given that there are no js errors except above one. jQuery is included correctly.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. But for example if you add open: true in the parameters, it works fine. Obviously it should work on click only. If someone has the answer please post it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem. I'm having a hard time trying to understand why exactly, but somewhere the colorbox is running in to a conflict because it also uses the name 'iframe' internally. Somehow this is causing a conflict when the classname 'iframe' is used as the class by which the function is called.

In my case changing

```
jQuery(".iframe").colorbox({iframe:true, width:"80%", height:"80%"});
```

to:

```
 jQuery(".photo_link").colorbox({iframe:true, width:"80%", height:"80%"});
```

worked.

Comment: i think the answer is not using CSS classes that will be DOM injected by the library

Answer (score 2):

Well this worked for me. Even though everything was in place and all the code was generated in the backend, for some reason colorbox wasn't picking up the links properly because on my page the link was inside a div that shows/hide on mouseover. Anyway, the way it worked for me was this one:

```
$(".iframe").live('click', function(e){
        $(this).colorbox({href: $(this).attr('href'), iframe:true, innerWidth:640, innerHeight:480, open:true});
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    });
```

In this way you rebind the actions to the element and then forces colorbox to open the link.

I hope it works for you and it isn't too late.

PS: If you're using jQuery 1.9+ you must use on instead of live

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same error and solved it by removing a duplicate call to colorbox. I had included both the library as well as my colorbox function in two separate include files. I figured it must be a duplicate because I had to close each colorbox window twice after it launched.

Check your code and make sure that the jquery.colorbox-min.js is only included once, as well as your function that calls it. In my case, my function was simple:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a.single_image").colorbox();
    $("a.link_preview").colorbox({iframe:true, width:"80%", height:"90%"});
});
```

After removing the duplicate calls, the problem went away. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this error **Error: cboxElement missing settings object** when making a second *jQuery* *on document ready function call* after the initial *on document ready function call* that holds the *colorbox parameters*.

**My situation:**

- On my pages I use and call just one external .js file that holds all
  my code.
- Inside the external .js file I have the *colorbox parameters* within a 
  *jQuery* *on document ready function*.
- On the troubled page (page with *cboxElement missing settings object

  error*), immediately following the external .js file I had some
  *jQuery* code that used the *on document ready function*: **$(function(){});**

**My problem:**

This second on document ready call caused and triggered the error **Error: cboxElement missing settings object** for me.

**My solution:**

The fix was as easy as changing the troubled pages code from using *jQuery's* *on document ready function* to using *Javascript's* native *self-executing anonymous function*.

```
(function(){
})();
```

Sure enough the error  **Error: cboxElement missing settings object** went away and everything works perfect!